# Bad latex output for Maple code

Tags: code, maple2e

I exported the maple code as Latex file and get the following undesirable output:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{maplestd2e}
 \def\emptyline{\vspace{12pt}}
 \begin{document}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Bullet Item}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 1}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Warning}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 4}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 2}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 3}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Dash Item}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Error}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Title}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Text Output}
 \DefineParaStyle{Maple Normal}
 \DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Output}
 \DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Input}
 \DefineCharStyle{Maple Maple Input}
 \DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Math}
 \DefineCharStyle{Maple Hyperlink}
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \mapleinline{inert}{2d}{with(DifferentialGeometry); -1}{\[\displaystyle \]}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \mapleinline{inert}{2d}{with(Tensor); -1}{\[\displaystyle \]}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \mapleinline{inert}{2d}{DifferentialGeometry:-DGsetup([x, y, z], M)}{\                              [\displaystyle {\it DGsetup} \left( [x,y,z],M \right) \]}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 \begin{maplegroup}
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \mapleinline{inert}{2d}{DifferentialGeometry:-DGsetup([x, y, z], M)}{\     [\displaystyle {\it DGsetup} \left( [x,y,z],M \right) \]}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 \mapleresult
 \begin{maplelatex}
 \mapleinline{inert}{2d}{`frame name: M`}{\[\displaystyle \mbox {{\tt `frame      name: M`}}\]}
 \end{maplelatex}
 \end{maplegroup}
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \mapleinline{inert}{2d}{a := DifferentialGeometry:-evalDG(D_x)}{\[\displaystyle a\, := \,{\it evalDG} \left( {\it D\_x} \right) \]}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 \begin{maplegroup}
 \begin{Maple Normal}{
 \mapleinline{inert}{2d}{a := DifferentialGeometry:-evalDG(D_x)}{\     [\displaystyle a\, := \,{\it evalDG} \left( {\it D\_x} \right) \]}
 }\end{Maple Normal}
 \mapleresult
 \begin{maplelatex}
 \mapleinline{inert}{2d}{_DG([["vector", M, []], [[[1], 1]]])}{\[\displaystyle \, DifferentialGeometry:-TeXVectorList[M][1]\]}
 \end{maplelatex}
 \end{maplegroup}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Does anybody know what is wrong? It is remarkable that the Latex file is compiled without any error.

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/65692) and edit your question to include that MWE? Without knowing what you are actually doing, we can't tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Is the file `maplestd2e.sty` available somewhere online

Comment: Yes. I added it from Maple installed location.

Comment: You can copy it from [here](http://users.wfu.edu/wickersg/latex/maple/maplestd2e.sty)

Comment: But It depends on [mapleenv.def](http://web.mit.edu/foley/sty/mapleenv.sty)