# LaTeX code which have been exported from Maple produce overpage equations

Tags: math-mode, maple2e

I want to typeset Maple code in LaTeX document. Export goes fine basically but long equations are overpaged. Do anybody know how to fix it?
I saw the  [same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333099/bad-latex-output-for-maple-code) without answer so I will try to ask again.

There are two files are need for typeset:
[mapleenv.def](http://web.mit.edu/foley/sty/mapleenv.def) 
[maplestd2e.sty](http://users.wfu.edu/wickersg/latex/maple/maplestd2e.sty)

[image]

There is a source:

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{article}
\usepackage{maplestd2e}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 1}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Text Output}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Dash Item}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Bullet Item}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Normal}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 4}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 3}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 2}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Warning}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Title}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Error}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple Hyperlink}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Math}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple Maple Input}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Output}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Input}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Plot}
\begin{Maple Normal}{
\begin{Maple Normal}{
\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{}{\[\displaystyle \]}
}\end{Maple Normal}
}\end{Maple Normal}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{restart:
}{}
\end{mapleinput}
\end{maplegroup}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{tn:=45:
kn:=5.12:
Rn:=1500:
}{}
\end{mapleinput}
\end{maplegroup}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{f:=unapply((256*(134.974933+13.87254679*t+0.3750534939e-1*t\symbol{94}2))* k/(R+67.48746650+6.936273395*t+ +0.1875267470e-1*t\symbol{94}2), t,k,R);
}{}
\end{mapleinput}
\mapleresult
\begin{maplelatex}
\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{f := proc (t, k, R) options operator, arrow; (256*134.974933+256*13.87254679*t+256*0.3750534939e-1*t^2)*k/(R+67.48746650+6.936273395*t+0.1875267470e-1*t^2) end proc}{\[\displaystyle f\, := \,( {t,k,R} )\mapsto {\frac { \left(  34553.58285+ 3551.371978\,t\\
\mbox{}+ 9.601369444\,{t}^{2} \right) k}{R+ 67.48746650+ 6.936273395\,t\\
\mbox{}+ 0.01875267470\,{t}^{2}}}\]}
\end{maplelatex}
\end{maplegroup}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{s1_3:=(R-Rn)*subs(\{t=tn, k=kn, R=Rn\}, diff(f(t,k,R), R));
}{}
\end{mapleinput}
\mapleresult
\begin{maplelatex}
\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{s1_3 := -.2977013542*R+446.5520313}{\[\displaystyle {\it s1\_3}\, := \,- 0.2977013542\,R+ 446.5520313\]}
\end{maplelatex}
\end{maplegroup}
\begin{maplegroup}
\begin{mapleinput}
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{ft:=unapply(s0_1 + s1_1 + s1_2 + s1_3 + s2_1 + s2_2 + s2_3 + s2_4 + s2_5 + s2_6, t,k,R);
}{}
\end{mapleinput}
\mapleresult
\begin{maplelatex}
\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{}{\[\displaystyle
{\it ft}\, := \,( {t,k,R} )\mapsto  31.5599036+ 9.222047288\,t\\
\mbox{}+ 111.4981076\,k- 0.2977013542\,R\\
\mbox{}- 0.02142132334\, \left( t-45 \right) ^{2}+ 1.801181112\, \left( t-45 \right)  \left( k- 5.12 \right) \\
\mbox{}- 0.003470321056\, \left( t-45 \right)  \left( R-1500 \right) - 0.05814479572\, \left( k- 5.12 \right)  \\ 
\mbox{} \left( R-1500 \right) \\
\mbox{}+ 0.0001552473382\, \left( R-1500 \right) ^{2}\]}
\end{maplelatex}
\end{maplegroup}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually comment 4 lines, then it works.  Do not ask me why. Maple generates the worst Latex code of any system I've seen.

Here is the new pdf

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here are the 4 lines you need to comments.

```
..... as before.....
\begin{maplegroup}
%\begin{mapleinput}    ======> THIS LINE
\mapleinline{active}{1d}{ft:=unapply(s0_1 + s1_1 + s1_2 + s1_3 + s2_1 + s2_2 + s2_3 + s2_4 + s2_5 + s2_6, t,k,R);
}{}
%\end{mapleinput}  ======> THIS LINE
\mapleresult
\begin{maplelatex}
%\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{}{    ======> THIS LINE
\[\displaystyle
{\it ft}\, := \,( {t,k,R} )\mapsto  31.5599036+ 9.222047288\,t\\
\mbox{}+ 111.4981076\,k- 0.2977013542\,R\\
\mbox{}- 0.02142132334\, \left( t-45 \right) ^{2}+ 1.801181112\, \left( t-45 \right)  \left( k- 5.12 \right) \\
\mbox{}- 0.003470321056\, \left( t-45 \right)  \left( R-1500 \right) - 0.05814479572\, \left( k- 5.12 \right)  \\ 
\mbox{} \left( R-1500 \right) \\
\mbox{}+ 0.0001552473382\, \left( R-1500 \right) ^{2}
\]
%}  ======> THIS LINE
\end{maplelatex}
\end{maplegroup}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast solution. By the way, this lines you may not comment `\begin{mapleinput}`...`\end{mapleinput}`. But other two indeed need to be comment for able equation breaking.